# Was there an effort to get rid or diminish the scope of the Wolf amendment?

Tags: united-states, china, nasa

> In an internal email on Wednesday, the US space agency said it had
> “certified its intent to Congress” to allow Nasa-funded researchers to
> apply to the CNSA for access to the lunar samples, collected by
> China’s Chang’e 5 mission in 2020.
>
> The applications would normally be illegal under the so-called Wolf
> Amendment – passed by the US Congress in 2011 and named after then
> Republican senator Frank Wolf – which bans Nasa from cooperating with
> China unless authorised by lawmakers.

https://archive.is/zD6MW#selection-821.0-833.242

Was there an effort to get rid or diminish the scope of the Wolf amendment? Seeing NASA made an application to make an exception of their recent application, I am wondering if there were any effort on revising the Wolf amendment to benefit NASA or any organization that might benefit from collaborating with China.